# How to jump back to the top of the code after if statement C language

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to make my program to start again from the beginning after user has selected an option from a menu.
When the user selects 1 and then enters the amount of the donation I want the program to start again and show the menu `What would you like to do?` and not to just restart just the if statement.

Should I add a for loop inside of the if statement to accomplish this? thanks for the help.

```
 printf("What would you like to do?\n");
    printf("      1 - Donate\n");
    printf("      2 - Invest\n");
    printf("      3 - Print balance\n");
    printf("      4 - Exit\n");
    printf("\n");

    //scans menu choice
    scanf("%d", &menu_option);

    if(menu_option==1)
    {
    printf("How much do you want to donate?\n");
    scanf("%lf", &donation);
    donations_made++;
    current_Balance = initial_Balance + donation;
    }
```

Comment: put all in a `for(;;) {` and do a `break;` to exit the loop in all cases except the case 1

Comment: Put it inside a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the user selects 1 and then enters the amount of the donation I want the program to start again and show the menu

just do

```
for(;;) {
  printf("      1 - Donate\n");
  printf("      2 - Invest\n");
  printf("      3 - Print balance\n");
  printf("      4 - Exit\n");
  printf("\n");

  //scans menu choice
  scanf("%d", &menu_option);

  if(menu_option==1)
  {
    printf("How much do you want to donate?\n");
    scanf("%lf", &donation);
    donations_made++;
    current_Balance = initial_Balance + donation;
    // NO BREAK
  }
  else {
    .... management of other cases
    break;
  }
}
```

or if you prefer

```
do {
  printf("      1 - Donate\n");
  printf("      2 - Invest\n");
  printf("      3 - Print balance\n");
  printf("      4 - Exit\n");
  printf("\n");

  //scans menu choice
  scanf("%d", &menu_option);

  if(menu_option==1)
  {
    printf("How much do you want to donate?\n");
    scanf("%lf", &donation);
    donations_made++;
    current_Balance = initial_Balance + donation;
  }
  // ... management of other cases
} while (menu_option==1);
```

But are you sure you do not want to redo also in cases 2 and 3 ? In that case replace `while (menu_option==1);` by `while (menu_option != 4);` or in the first proposal do the `break` only when `menu_option` is 4

I also encourage you to check the return value of `scanf("%d", &menu_option);` to be sure a valid integer was given in input and `menu_option` was set

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
 int menu_option;
 double donation;
 int donations_made = 0;
 int current_Balance = 0;
 int initial_Balance = 0;

 for (;;)
 {

    printf("What would you like to do?\n");
    printf("      1 - Donate\n");
    printf("      2 - Invest\n");
    printf("      3 - Print balance\n");
    printf("      4 - Exit\n");
    printf("\n");

    //scans menu choice
    scanf("%d", &menu_option);

            if (menu_option==1)
            {
                   printf("How much do you want to donate?\n");
                   scanf("%lf", &donation);
                   donations_made++;
                   current_Balance = initial_Balance + donation;
             }
        else if (menu_option == 4)
                 break;

   }
}
```